# How to rebuild route cache programmatically

Tags: 8

I installed a module quizzard and after uninstallation I am getting this error

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "quizard.quizard_config_form" does not exist." at /home/paddu008/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php line 190
```

So how do I rebuild route cache programmatically.

Comment: You can also use this as guide - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43648987/7528823

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to clear route cache programmatically in drupal 8, use the following:

```
\Drupal::service('router.builder')->rebuild();
```

Comment: This can be run from the command line as `drush eval '\Drupal::service("router.builder")->rebuild();'`

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild cache programmatically execute: `drush cr`

Comment: no i cant install drush due to space requirements

Comment: how we can do this programmatically without drush command?

Answer (score 1):

**On Exact Cases** such as `hook_preprocess_pager(&$variables) {...`

You can also use

> `$variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
>   \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger(); 
>   cache_clear_all() // For Drupal-7
>   drupal_flush_all_caches() // For Drupal-8`
>
> You can also use this as guide - **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608217/how-to-clear-cache-programmatically-in-drupal-8**